# Crash on Target Sdk Version 26 or Higher

Tags: android, xml, sdk, crash

I'm a new Android programmer and recently,my projects have been getting this crash on device run android 8 and android 9 when i target Sdk Version to 26 or higher. This is my crash log :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.westland/com.htmlchrome.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2816)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6652)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary 
XML file line #10: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error 
inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.htmlchrome.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6652)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{f41086b 
13155:com.cowboygunfighter.westland/u0a160} (pid=13155, uid=10160) requires 
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
at org.xwalk.core.ReflectConstructor.newInstance(ReflectConstructor.java:54)
at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.reflectionInit(XWalkView.java:788)
at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:221)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{f41086b 
13155:com.cowboygunfighter.westland/u0a160} (pid=13155, uid=10160) requires 
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2005)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1951)
at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.registerContentObserver(IContentService.java:768)
at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1940)
at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:1929)
at org.xwalk.core.internal.extension.api.contacts.Contacts.<init>(Contacts.java:42)
at org.xwalk.core.internal.extension.BuiltinXWalkExtensions.load(BuiltinXWalkExtensions.java:62)
at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewInternal.initXWalkContent(XWalkViewInternal.java:365)
at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewInternal.<init>(XWalkViewInternal.java:253)
at org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge.<init>(XWalkViewBridge.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at org.xwalk.core.ReflectConstructor.newInstance(ReflectConstructor.java:48)
... 28 more
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>
```

My styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="SelectPopupDialog">
    <item name="select_dialog_singlechoice">@android:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice</item>
    <item name="select_dialog_multichoice">@android:layout/select_dialog_multichoice</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="SelectActionMenuShare">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
</style> 
<style name="SelectActionMenuWebSearch">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.htmlchrome;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost;
import com.chartboost.sdk.CBLocation;
import com.chartboost.sdk.ChartboostDelegate;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub;
import org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AdView adView;
private InterstitialAd admobExit;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
private String link = "";
private boolean showAdmobExit = false;
private String url_offline = "file:///android_asset/www/index.html";
private String url_online = "";
private final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
private XWalkView webview;

private class JSInterface {
    private InterstitialAd admob;

    class C05181 implements Runnable {
        C05181() {
        }

        public void run() {
            JSInterface.this.admob.loadAd(new Builder().build());
            Log.e("RUN:", "loadAdmobFull");
        }
    }

    class C05192 implements Runnable {
        C05192() {
        }

        public void run() {
            JSInterface.this.admob.show();
        }
    }

    class C05214 implements Runnable {
        C05214() {
        }

        public void run() {
            Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    class C05225 implements Runnable {
        C05225() {
        }

        public void run() {
            Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    class C05236 implements Runnable {
        C05236() {
        }

        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.adView.setVisibility(0);
            MainActivity.this.adView.loadAd(new Builder().build());
        }
    }

    class C05247 implements Runnable {
        C05247() {
        }

        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.adView.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    class C05258 implements Runnable {
        C05258() {
        }

        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.vunglePub.playAd();
        }
    }

    public JSInterface() {
        this.admob = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        this.admob.setAdUnitId(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.admob_full));
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void loadAdmobFull() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05181());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAdmobFull() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05192());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAdmobFullOnExit(final boolean isShow) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.showAdmobExit = isShow;
            }
        });
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void loadChartboot() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05214());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showChartBoot() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05225());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAdmobBanner() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05236());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void hideAdmobBanner() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05247());
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showVungle() {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new C05258());
    }
}

class C10261 extends AdListener {
    C10261() {
    }

    public void onAdLoaded() {
        if (MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    public void onAdOpened() {
    }

    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
    this.webview = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    this.adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    this.vunglePub.init(this, getString(R.string.vungle_id));
    this.interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    this.interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_full));
    this.interstitialAd.loadAd(new Builder().build());
    this.interstitialAd.setAdListener(new C10261());
    this.link = getString(R.string.link);
    this.webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSInterface");
    this.webview.load(this.link, null);
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, getString(R.string.chartboot_id), getString(R.string.chartboot_sign));
    Chartboost.onCreate(this);
    Chartboost.onStart(this);
    this.admobExit = new InterstitialAd(this);
    this.admobExit.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_full));
    this.admobExit.loadAd(new Builder().build());
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, getString(R.string.chartboot_id), getString(R.string.chartboot_sign));
    Chartboost.onStart(this);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Chartboost.onResume(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Chartboost.onPause(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Chartboost.onStop(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Chartboost.onDestroy(this);
}
```

I know it happen when i target sdk version to 26 or higher but i dont know why it happen. Can anyone help me solve this problem for me please ??

Answer (score 0):

I come to help you a little from vlance. Error may come from the old crosswalk plugin, crosswalk project has been canceled over years, they don't update it anymore. There 2 ways: you switch to another html5 library, phonegap maybe or try to update to latest version.